# Django: How to update a related model when create an other model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models: Transaction and Wallet, a wallet has multiple transactions.
I need to update the `amount` field in `Wallet` model whenever a new transaction is created. The way I see is overwrite `save` method in the model. Currently, I wrote like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    if self.kind == "Income":
        self.wallet.amount += self.amount
    elif self.kind == "Outcome":
        self.wallet.amount -= self.amount
    self.wallet.save()
    super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It creates a new transaction correctly but not update the wallet model. How I can fix that?

Comment: What class is this method located in?

Comment: this method save is inside the Transaction Model or Wallet model ?

Comment: this save method is inside Transaction model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check to see that your conditional statements are getting triggered?

This should actually work without you having to call self.wallet.save() if
you have already passed a valid Wallet object to the Transaction.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    if self.kind == "Income":
        self.wallet.amount += self.amount
    elif self.kind == "Outcome":
        self.wallet.amount -= self.amount
    super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects

For information on how to save Object references.

So I think two things could be going wrong. Either your conditional statements are not getting triggered, or you are not passing a valid Wallet Object reference to the Transaction.

Either way...I think this is a good use case for Django's signals. First, I would remove the save method you have, and in the Transaction model I would add

```
def update_transaction_wallet(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.kind == "Income":
        instance.wallet.amount += instance.amount
    elif instance.kind == "Outcome":
        instance.wallet.amount -= instance.amount

signals.post_save.connect(update_transaction_wallet, sender=Transaction)
```

You may have to tweak this a bit in order for it to work in your specific case. You didn't provide a lot of information about your models and situation.

But basically, this bit of code tells Django that whenever a Transaction Objects gets saved to also run the update_transaction_wallet() method. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Comment: Yeah, like you said my condition hasn't got trigger. You are my lifesaver. Thank you so much

Comment: I got another problem. Do you know how to not create a new transaction if the amount of transaction greater than the amount of wallet and return an error message for the user?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing this because that information can be accessed via aggregate functions. Check out on [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/).

But, if for some specific reason you you need to do it, you need to do it after the transaction is saved, with F expression:

```
from django.db.models import F

def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.kind == "Income":
        self.wallet.amount = F('amount') + self.amount
    elif self.kind == "Outcome":
        self.wallet.amount = F('amount') - self.amount
    self.wallet.save()
```

Comment: I just try it but the amount of wallet still the same as before

Comment: I just noticed, you need to use F object for such cases, I updated my answer.

Comment: It because my condition didn't trigger. It should be self.kind.name === "Income". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate Wallet and then make the proper addition or subtraction on it.

I would do it inside a Transaction method,
which you will call on save or any other place.
and if saves fail, rowback the wallet amount too ;)